# In java networking, can I get the domain name via which the client tried to access the server?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

Let's say user1 tried to access my server at 11.11.11.11 using foo1.com
and user2 tried to access my server at 11.11.11.11 using foo2.net

is it possible to differentiate those requests when programming with Java + servlet?

Thanks : )

Comment: As he is using a servlet, I assumed he is using HTTP(S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the HTTP GET comes in you get the original URL. This means you don't actually get the IP address the client tries to connect to. e.g. if the request is forwarded, BNATed or proxied.

In short, you only have the URL, which includes the host name. You can look in the header and perhaps the client will tell you what IP address its connected to.

Comment: thanks for the answer:) 

Also... is this only possible on http(s) requests? What about requests using ssh, (s)ftp, and other services???

Comment: Only for the protocols which contain the hostname can you share a IP on the server and determine the hostname used. Another solution is to give the server multiple IP addresses, one for each hostname. On linux a network adapter can have ~250 ip addresses.